# Thread Safe instance variables in Ruby MRI

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I've already searched other Stack Overflow posts and researched elsewhere, and I'm familiar with threads on a broad level, I just need some clarification for this specific case, as native ruby threads aren't parallel threads as I'm used to in jruby, and I don't fully understand green threads as much as I do OS level threads.

### Given the Criteria:

- I need to fire off a mailer within a class instance.
- The mailer needs access to data stored in an instance attribute.
- I don't care about the success of the thread.
- I don't want the threads success or failure to interrupt my main thread.

### Which is better?

Should I reference the original instance variable directly, or should I instead do a clone of that instance variable?

this works, but I'm worried @foo could be lost before the thread finishes:

```
@foo = { bar: "baz" }
Thread.new { Mailer.notice(@foo).deliver }
```

wondering if I should be doing something like this instead:

```
@foo = { bar: "baz" }
Thread.new { Mailer.notice(@foo.freeze.clone).deliver }
```

### Responses

In the form of cited examples or articles would be greatly appreciated. Real tests would be even more valuable if anyone has the time to write such an example!

Comment: What do you mean, they aren't real threads? They are.

Comment: By real threads, I mean parallel

Comment: The object in `@foo` won't be "lost" *after* supplied as an argument of the method - the resulting object and *not* the variable are of relevance. Assuming that the object resulting from the evaluation of `@foo` is *immutable* then both code snippets have the exact same issues - which is to say that it could be the case that `@foo` is *re-assigned* before the thread runs.

Comment: @user2864740: ruby threads are not green since 1.9

Comment: is it worth doing a freeze and clone then to ensure the data will remain in tact from the time the thread is fired, or am I mostly safe just referencing the original instance var as-is?

Comment: Treat the threads the same as in JRuby and you will be fine. Regardless of whether they run true parallel or not, they do run concurrently and that gives plenty of scope for race conditions and unwanted changes. The possible switch point for non-parallel threads  in MRI is between each method call or expression (with a few exceptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is either. Since I am using >1.9 the threads are not green, and both methods are the same from a lifecycle point of view.